# Java - Why do instantly executed lambda functions raise "Multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface [...]"?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

```
List<String> list = ( () -> new LinkedList<String>() )();
```

The code above raises the following: `Multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface java.util.List`.

What is the meaning of this error?

Comment: Your Javascript syntax is confusing the compiler. He thinks you think `List` is a functional interface.

Comment: Java is not C.  The final `()` looks like an attempt to call a method… but you omitted the method name.  If you were trying to imply a Supplier, it should be `.get()`.  Of course, I doubt even that will compile, unless you cast the lambda to a `Supplier<List<String>>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not the error message I get, although it is certainly invalid Java syntax.

You cannot call a lambda expression directly in Java syntax.  The compiler has no grammar production for converting a lambda expression for the purposes of calling it directly.

Either it must be assigned to a functional interface type, passed as an argument to a method, or cast to a functional interface type.

If you cast the lambda expression to a functional interface type (here, `Supplier`), then you can call it explicitly.

```
List<String> list = ( (Supplier<List<String>>)  () -> new LinkedList<String>() ).get();
```